# Why can we talk of electric potential under AC?

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, potential, voltage, maxwell-equations

An electric potential $V$ is defined by the relation $E = - \nabla{V}$. The existence of such a potential is true in electrostatic (constant electro-magnetic field) because of the Maxwell-Faraday equation.

Now my question is: how can we talk of potentials in the context of a circuit under an alternative current (or other non-constant generator)?

Since the electrostatic condition no longer holds, how are we sure this potential is defined?

Comment: When the frequency is low the non-potential component of the field is small and we ignore it. When the frequency is higher we use radio wave approximations instead of electrostatic approximations.

Comment: Richard Feynman talks a bit about this here, in the context of inductors: https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_22.html.

Answer (score 1):

There is a family of low-frequency approximations of Maxwell equations.

One of them is sometimes called "magnetic" low frequency approximation. In it, you still consider the $\partial\vec{E}/\partial t$ term in the Maxwell-Ampère equation negligible, but you do restore the $\partial\vec{B}/\partial t$ term in the Maxwell-Faraday equation:
$$\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{E}+\frac{\partial\vec{B}}{\partial t}=\vec{0}$$

Because of this, as you said, the relation $\vec{E}=-\vec{\nabla}V$ no longer holds. This would mean that voltage is no longer defined and Kirchhoff's voltage law no longer holds.

However, to make a long story short, in the context of electricity with this magnetic low frequency approximation, you can still use $V$ as defined in the static case, provided that you add an extra term to Kirchhoff's voltage law to make it valid again.

This extra term is the so-called electromotive force:
$$e=-\frac{d\phi}{dt}$$
with $\phi$ the magnetic flux across the circuit.

In the absence of any magnetic field, $e=0$, which means the existence of $V$ and the validity of Kirchhoff's voltage law are restored as in the static case. It's an approximation, but it works extremely well in most practical cases (in metal conductors).

If you want to step outside of any low frequency approximation, then you can prove the existence of two potentials $V$ and $\vec{A}$, such that:
$$\vec{E}=-\vec{\nabla}V-\frac{\partial\vec{A}}{\partial t}$$
So you can still define an electric potential, but due to the other term, it doesn't work as in the static case.